# iOS taking a screen capture of your app before going into background when orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, orientation

I know this question was asked before, however I need a more specific answer regarding orientation changes,
When i add the view that hides the sensitive data to the app, press the home button, and then change the iPad orientation and go back to the app, the view stays at portrait frame which is not the correct since I changed the orientation and it doesn't cover the entire screen.

Anyone knows how to handle this?

Comment: show some code? or explain more how the view is managed. If you create it progammatically you need to if a view controller work with viewWillLayoutSubviews or if a view layoutSubviews.

Comment: @LanternMike its just a simple UIViewController with a background color.

Comment: i'm unclear on how you added the view, is it a UIView that is added to a Viewcontroller to cover it up? Is it added with addSubview?

Comment: I've tried several ways. Even the simplest approach of adding a view controller and changing the content's view background color doesn't work.

Comment: the autoresizingMask of UIView is suppose to be automatic. When a parent view changes the view can have rules like stretch to fit. Normally it's off by default and there is no automatic re-sizing unless you modify the autoresizingMask. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask